# How to extend 'old style' dojox widgets?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dojo, amd

I've already written my own dijit widgets, as well as extended the existing one. It's simply making new declare with extended widget as argument, and using the own one instead of extended one.

However, I have a problem with `dojox/form/Uploader`, because it's that 'old-style' widget using old-style syntax. Instead of using the object returned by `require`, one should use the global object:

```
  require(['dojox/form/Uploader'], function(Uploader){
    var u = new dojox.form.Uploader({})
    u.startup()
  })
```

So, if I want to extend that widget, and using the child 'class' instead of the original, how should I actually do that?

Another thing I don't fully understand is, why whe need to use that 'old-style' syntax for `dojox/form/Uploader`, because it's created with the same syntax as 'normal' widget:

```
    return declare("dojox.form.Uploader", [Base, Button, HTML5, IFrame, Flash], {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can extend it just like a 'new style' (AMD) widget, i.e.:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojox/form/Uploader"
], function(decl) {
    var MyUploader = decl(dojox.form.Uploader, {
        buildRendering: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.domNode.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(" ← awesome"));
        }
    });
    new MyUploader({}).placeAt("x").startup();
});
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question? The reason there are traces of the 'old style' syntax in Uploader (and some other widgets) is probably just because nobody has had the time to port it to the new style yet (so it was probably automatically "converted").

**Edit:** Actually, the Uploader returns a 'new style' object in addition to setting the dojox.form.Uploader global. So you can actually change the above example to:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    "dojox/form/Uploader"
], function(decl, Uploader) {
    var MyUploader = decl(Uploader, {
    ....
```

since `Uploader === dojox.form.Uploader` here.

Comment: The exact point that was to me unclear was, that I shouldn't use 'Uploader' variable but 'dojox.form.Uploader' global reference. I wasn't sure what to refer withit `declare`.

Comment: It's somewhat confusing, yeah. Actually, my answer is confusing too, you probably _shouldn't_ use the global dojox.form.Uploader, since it actually does return a 'new style' object in addition to setting the global dojox.form.Uploader.